# How to use a mirror of security.ubuntu.com?

Tags: linux-mint, repository

I don't have access to `http://security.ubuntu.com`.

In the Software Sources settings, I already selected a mirror for Base (trusty). But when I update, I see that it is still using `http://security.ubuntu.com`. It takes forever because it gets no data.

How can I fix this?

P.S. I am using Linux Mint 17.3 Cinnamon.

Comment: Is that meant to be `security.ubuntu.com`?

Comment: You (or your network administrator) need to fix whatever problem is causing you not to have access to `security.ubuntu.com`.

Comment: @Gilles This is not an option at the moment :(

Answer (score 1):

You can edit `/etc/apt/sources.list` manually.

Find any lines contains `security.ubuntu.com` and replace it with your mirror.

Note: it requires root privilege to edit that file

Comment: My `sources.list` only contains the following two lines:


`#deb cdrom:[Linux Mint 17.3 _Rosa_ - Release amd64 20151128]/ trusty contrib main non-free

deb http://cran.rstudio.com/bin/linux/ubuntu trusty/`

Comment: @becko Try the files in the directory `/etc/apt/sources.list.d`.

Comment: @RealSkeptic Found it, thanks. Can you suggest a mirror for `security.ubuntu.com`?

Comment: @becko You might find [this answer on AskUbuntu](http://askubuntu.com/a/185444/465173) useful.

Comment: @becko `security.ubuntu.com` isn't supposed to have mirrors. You're supposed to download from the primary site, so that you always get up-to-date updates.